# PHP array with keys as file's creation date

Tags: php, sorting, date, glob

So I've got a folder, `path/to/folder`, with folders within folders and files within folders, etc.---all within one folder `path/to/folder`. I want to store all the names of all the images (.gif, .png, .jpg, .jpeg, etc.) in this folder `path/to/folder` like so (my attempt):

```
$arr = glob("path/to/folder/*.jpg");//not sure how to specify or "|" here
```

I also need the dates associated with the images' metadata (date created) like so (see psuedocode below):

```
foreach($arr as $a){
    $date_of_a = function_getting_dates_of_a($a);//filectime?
    $newArr[$date_of_a]=function_getting_names_of_a($a);//names are filtered by a pattern
                      //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^I've already created this.
}
```

This way I can have same name *values* with different *keys*, which would be dates, and so two same-name-and-same-date pairs (or tuples depending on how many duplicates) would condense to one unique name-date item. For example,

```
2016-01-01 => path/to/folder/.../name1.jpg//*duplicate name-date pair
2016-01-02 => path/to/folder/.../name2.jpg
2016-01-01 => path/to/folder/.../name1.jpg//*duplicate name-date pair
2016-01-02 => path/to/folder/.../name1.jpg
```

would reduce the array to

```
2016-01-01 => path/to/folder/.../name1.jpg//*only one now
2016-01-02 => path/to/folder/.../name2.jpg
2016-01-02 => path/to/folder/.../name1.jpg
```

Here, `/.../`, means "any number of folders within `path/to/folder`". The data I'm dealing with would imply that `2016-01-01 => path/to/folder/.../name1.jpg` and `2016-01-02 => path/to/folder/.../name1.jpg` are two identical objects made at different times. I want to, in the end, be able to count how many instances of each name there are using `array_count_values`.

---

### ATTEMPT

```
<?php

    $myArray = glob("path/to/folder/*.jpg");
    foreach($myArray as $item){
        $date = filectime($item);//What if no date? Is that possible?
        if(preg_match('/PATTERN/',$item,$match)==1){
            $newArr[$date]=current($match);
        }
    }
    array_count_values($newArr);
    <!-- CODE TO GRAPH ITEMS BY FREQUENCY-->
?>
```

Comment: Do you have any example code for your attempted solution?

Comment: How could 2 identical objects have a different date? From what you write, the path is the same?

Comment: Files can have the same date, either different filenames or the same in different dirs.

Comment: @Eric, you're right, the path could be different; however, `function_getting_names_of_a` will match a pattern for specifically named images, and so the file path will not be considered. I have already written `function_getting_names_of_a`, but excluded it here.

Comment: @Eric, by "identical objects" I mean what the data represents and of the conduct of business. An image taken on another date with the same name represents two unique "objects;" for example, banana is a name, and you can have two bananas, and so in this way they are considered "identical" because they are bananas. Does that make sense?

Comment: Going along with my banana metaphor, `date1 => banana`, `date2 => banana` would mean someone took a picture of a banana, and then took another picture of a different banana.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should create an array of date-time keys:

```
<?php

$myArray = glob("/*.jpg");
$newArr = array();
foreach($myArray as $item){
    $timestamp = filectime($item);
    if ($timestamp === false) {
        continue;
    }
    $date = new \DateTime();
    $date->setTimestamp($timestamp);
    $formattedDate = $date->format('m-d-Y');
    $newArr[$formattedDate]=$item;
}
array_count_values($newArr);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($newArr);
//<!-- CODE TO GRAPH ITEMS BY FREQUENCY-->
```

And this is what gets printed out when I have multiple JPG files created on the same day:

```
Array
(
    [04-12-2016] => sdfdsf.jpg
)
```

As for finding files recursively, you can try these functions, which I've used in my own personal projects:

```
function findDirectories($rootPath) {
    $directories = array();
    foreach (glob($rootPath . "/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $directory) {
        $directories[] = $directory;
    }
    return $directories;
}

function findFiles($rootPath, $extension) {
    $files = array();
    foreach (glob($rootPath . "/*.$extension") as $file) {
        $files[] = $file;
    }
    return $files;
}

function findFilesRecursive($rootPath,$extension) {
    $files = findFiles($rootPath,$extension);
    $directories = findDirectories($rootPath);
    if (!empty($directories)) {
        foreach ($directories as $key=>$directory) {
            $foundFiles = findFilesRecursive($directory,$extension);
            foreach ($foundFiles as $foundFile) {
                $files[] = $foundFile;
            }
        }
    }
    return $files;
}
```

Comment: `findFilesRecursive($directory);` should be `findFilesRecursive($directory,'jpg');` Your personal project functions work quite nicely. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I fixed the answer. Glad to have helped!